# How to return dynamic numberOfItemsInSection in UICollectionview

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell, uitableviewsectionheader

I have `viewForHeaderInSection` in `UITableView` based on `viewForHeaderInSection` data each `UITableviewCell` have `UICollectionView` in `UICollectionViewCell` I have to show data for "product" and "qty" the count of each "product" and "qty" is different for each `viewForHeaderInSection`. I am able to achieve tableview header and cell data but I am not able to get `UICollectionViewCell` data based on `UITableViewHeader` data in the json  "order_id", "order_unique_id","store_name" and  "otp_store" is tableview header section data and "user_details" is `tableviewcell` data for `uicollectionviewcell` "product" and "qty"

```
   {
"status": "1",
"error": false,
"data": [
    {
        "order_id": "11",
        "order_unique_id": "ORDR-1001",
        "store_name": "24X7",
        "otp_store": "781103",
        "product": [
            "Product One",
            "Product Two"
        ],
        "qty": [
            "1",
            "3"
        ],
        "user_details": {
            "name": "Pankaj Ravi",
            "number": "0999889",
            "landmark": "PBH",
            "area": "Bow East",
            "pincode": "E3 9EG",
            "place": "Home"
        },
        "status": "2",
        "date": "2018-12-13",
        "time": "14:37:57"
    },
    {
        "order_id": "1",
        "order_unique_id": "ORDR-988",
        "store_name": "24X7",
        "otp_store": "957505",
        "product": [
            "Product Eight"
        ],
        "qty": [
            "1"
        ],
        "user_details": {
            "name": “Jhon”,
            "number": “999996",
            "landmark": “Ithum",
            "area": "Bow East",
            "pincode": "E3 9EG",
            "place": "Office"
        },
        "status": "0",
        "date": "2018-11-24",
        "time": "12:41:02"
    }
]
}
```

Code For UITableview

```
      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    print(section)
    let headerCell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomHeaderCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomHeaderCell
    if runnerArray.count > 0 {
        headerCell.btnHeader.setTitle("\("x " + runnerArray[section].order_unique_id)", for: UIControl.State.normal)
        var status = runnerArray[section].status
        if status == "0" {
            status = "Pending"
        } else if status == "1" {
            status = "Dispatch"
        } else {
             status = "Complete"
        }
    let lblHeaderText = status + " " + runnerArray[section].time + " , " + runnerArray[section].date
    headerCell.lblHeader.text =  lblHeaderText
    return headerCell
    } else {
        return UIView()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return runnerArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 400
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell {

        cell.setDataForOTPStoreAndName(runner: runnerArray[indexPath.section])
        cell.setDataForProduct(userDetails: userDetailsArray[indexPath.section])
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Code For UICollectionView Cell

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //Note:- Here i am not able to find how to return array count based on UItableviewheadersection data
    return productArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductsCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? ProductsCollectionViewCell {
        cell.lblProductName.text = productArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

Comment: plz past your full code of `tableview` and `collectionview` delegate and datasource method

Comment: @PratikPrajapati added code of UITableview and UICollectionview

Comment: In tableView `cellForRowAt` method you have to pass your collection data, like `cell.productArray  =  runnerArray[indexPath.section].product ` and  `cell.productArray  =  runnerArray[indexPath.section].qty ` then reload your collectionview in `cell.collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: @PratikPrajapati Thanks a lot it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you add this code to show number of header and each header add one row,then pass one section object to table cell use below code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

var dataArry : [DataObj]?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "response", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
            let jsonObj = try JSONDecoder().decode(Modal.self, from: data)
            self.dataArry = jsonObj.data
            print("jsonData:\(jsonObj)")
        } catch let error {
            print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    } else {
        print("Invalid filename/path.")
    }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if let count = self.dataArry?.count {
        return count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RowCell") as? RowCell
    cell?.updateCell(dataObj: self.dataArry?[indexPath.section] ?? DataObj())
    return cell!
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as? HeaderCell
    cell?.textLabel?.text = dataArry?[section].store_name
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200
}

}
```

then add this code in your tableview cell class

```
func updateCell(dataObj:DataObj)  {
    self.dataObj = dataObj
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        if let count = self.dataObj?.product?.count {
            return count
        }
    }else if section == 1 {
        if let count = self.dataObj?.qty?.count {
            return count
        }
    }
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
        cell?.titlelbl.text =  self.dataObj?.product?[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as?
            CollectionViewCell
        //cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        cell?.titlelbl.text = self.dataObj?.qty?[indexPath.row]
        return cell!
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
}
```

}